# How do I make the same change to multiple branches in perforce

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

If I do

```
p4 integrate foo/file bar/file
p4 submit
```

and then want to make substantially the same change to both copies in a single submit, is there a better way than just p4 editing both of them and doing the submit?

Answer (score 2):

Making edits directly to both files is the wrong way to do it.

Running the `p4 integrate` command is letting perforce know that there should be a relationship between the files.

You should edit just one of the files, submit it, then you should do another  [integrate](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_integrate.html)/[merge](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_merge.html)/[resolve](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_resolve.html).

Comment: Unfortunately I need the submit to be atomic in this particular case.  If I understand correctly, integrate can't be used that way.

Comment: That seems like a bass ackwards requirement, but you could do it that way, and then use integrate to update the integration history.

Comment: "Bass-ackwards" doesn't even begin to describe it :-)  Can you give me an idea of what that integrate command would look like?

Comment: If you have existing branches setup and in place, the command is as simple as `p4 integrate -b <branchname>`